Unable to update a latent vector using custom loss function in pytorch
I am trying to implement this function but have had no luck. There is a VAE model that I am using, and along with it, there are encoder and decoder. I'm freezing the weights of the VAE decoder, and trying to change a latent vector which is updated using the function optimize_latent_vector(model, inp__, num_epochs=50, learning_rate=0.01). Now, there is some error regarding this piece of code: RuntimeError: element 0 of tensors does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn

class VAE_GD_Loss(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(VAE_GD_Loss, self).__init__()

    def forward(self, bad_seg, recons_mask, vector):
        # l2 normed squared and the soft dice loss are calculated
        loss = torch.sum(vector**2)+Soft_Dice_Loss(recons_mask, bad_seg)
        return loss

def optimize_latent_vector(model, inp__, num_epochs=50, learning_rate=0.01):
    inp__ = inp__.to(device).requires_grad_(True)
    # Encode and reparameterize to get initial latent vector
    with torch.no_grad():
        mu, log_var = model.encoder(inp__)
        z_latent_vect = model.reparameterize(mu, log_var)
    optimizer_lat = torch.optim.Adam([z_latent_vect], lr=learning_rate)
    dec_only = model.decoder
    
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        optimizer_lat.zero_grad()
        dec_only.eval()
        # Decode from latent vector
        recons_mask = dec_only(z_latent_vect)
        # Calculate loss
        VGLoss = VAE_GD_Loss()
        loss = VGLoss(inp__, recons_mask, z_latent_vect)
        # loss = Variable(loss, requires_grad=True)
        # Backpropagation
        loss.backward()
        optimizer_lat.step()
        print(f"Epoch {epoch}: Loss = {loss.item()}")
    
    return z_latent_vect

If we uncomment the line loss = Variable(loss, requires_grad=True), then the code runs, but it doesn't minimize the loss whatsoever. I want to update the latent vector in such a way so that it follows the constraint set in the loss function. Any leads would help!

What version of pytorch are you using? Variable syntax has been depreciated since 2020

I'm using torch '2.4.0', okay, will keep that in mind. Thanks a lot!

I think your z_latent_vect is not enabled for gradient computation at all. It is initialised in a no_grad() block and is detached from the rest of the computation graph. Defining it as a torch.nn.Parameter should do the trick. At least I can see the loss decrease on a very simple VAE that I defined.
def optimize_latent_vector(model, inp__, num_epochs=50, learning_rate=0.01):
    inp__ = inp__.to(device)

    with torch.no_grad():
        mu, log_var = model.encoder(inp__)
        z_latent_vect = model.reparameterize(mu, log_var)

    z_latent_vect = torch.nn.Parameter(z_latent_vect.clone(), requires_grad=True)
    optimizer_lat = optim.Adam([z_latent_vect], lr=learning_rate)

    dec_only = model.decoder
    VGLoss = VAE_GD_Loss()

    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        optimizer_lat.zero_grad()
        dec_only.eval()

        recons_mask = dec_only(z_latent_vect)
        loss = VGLoss(inp__, recons_mask, z_latent_vect)

        loss.backward()
        # print(loss.item()) you should see it reduce here
        optimizer_lat.step()

    return z_latent_vect


Yes, thanks a lot, you are right. I had done a torch.no_grad() in some other block that was calling another function, which was calling this function, hence missed this part. Your answer did the job for me!
